# Select multiple text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having 2 problems

1. I'm able to select **One word**, but I want to select multiple words (next to each other) 
   with my mouse and then highlight them, and then the dropdown should appear the way that we get with clicking on one word.
2. when I select one word, the drop-down appears, when I click on the other it is making the 2nd word in red color but the drop-down is gone. I'm unable to know how to change the toggle thing. Any word I select, it should be red and show drop-down. and if there is no red text, there should be no drop-down...

```js
var words = $("p:first").text().split(" ");
var text = words.join("</span> <span>");
$("p:first").html("<span>" + text + "</span>");

$("span").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  //$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  /* user-agent specific */
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  /* etc... */
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>

<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()"> <a href="#about">About</a> <a href="#base">Base</a> <a href="#blog">Blog</a> <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#custom">Custom</a> <a href="#support">Support</a> <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
</div>
```

Here is the working example: [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/b3z4rp6j/)

Comment: You can use `window.getSelection().toString()` to get the selected text. Using this, you can check if user has selected 2 words or more/less. This should be your starting point.

Comment: So - when do you want to show the dropdown, and when do you want to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the previous and next span for the class `active`. If at least one of these two conditions are true then add the `show` class, else remove it:

```
$("span").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('active');

   if ($(this).next().hasClass('active') || $(this).prev().hasClass('active'))
       document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.add("show");
   else
       document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");

   //$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/ytnhvoak/1/

Comment: Of course you can use the jQuery equivalent [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) if you want to be consistant

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, I mistyped it, I meant multiple words in the sense, two words one after other. For eg.  `Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.` when I select both `Click on`, the dropdown should come up.

Comment: You may want to consider removing the `active` class from all but the current item in the `else` clause so that you don't end up with lots of random unconnected highlighted words. But i'll leave that to you

Answer (score 0):

Please try this js code

```
  <script>
        var words = $("p:first").text().split(" ");
        var text = words.join("</span> <span>");
        $("p:first").html("<span>" + text + "</span>");

        $("span").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            if ($( this ).hasClass( "active" )) {
                $("#myDropdown").show();
            } else {
                if ( ! $("p:first span").hasClass("active")) {
                    $("#myDropdown").hide();
                }

            }
            //$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
        });
    </script>
```

This may will help you

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, I mistyped it, I meant multiple words in the sense, two words one after other. For eg. `Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link`. when I select both `Click on`, the dropdown should come up.